# Material UI Autocomplete not working as expected, does not accept commas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Below is an example for their documentation. I'm trying to allow the user to use commas, to select multiple values from the dropdown.

If the input is `Part 1`, the component works just fine, but if the input is `Part 1, Part 2`, or just simply `1,2`, then the component seems to think that there are no options to select from.

I've tried adding the `freeSolo` prop, but that didn't work.

What's going on here?

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/core/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      multiple
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { label: "Part 1", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Part 2", year: 1972 },
  { label: "Part 3", year: 1974 },
];
```

[image: combobox-material-demo-forked-ni958?]

Answer (score -1):

For anyone coming here in the future, I managed to fix this by adding the [`filterOptions`](https://next.material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) prop.